# Async Future Promise not working in Swift 5

Tags: swift, firebase, asynchronous, combine

I'm trying to implement an async call to a function loadUserFromFirebase and populate and return an array based on user attributes that I then use to write to a firebase collection.

I'm trying to use the Combine framework from Swift using future and promises but for some reason, the receiveCompletion and receiveValue don't get called and thus I get an empty array from my async function call.

Here is my code:

```
var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    func loadUserFromFirebase(groupUserIds: [String], handler: @escaping ([groupMate]) -> Void) {
        
        var groupmateID = 0
        var groupMates : [groupMate] = []
        print("groupUserIds: \(groupUserIds)" )
        
        for groupUserUID in groupUserIds {
            print("groupUserUID: \(groupUserUID)" )
            
            let future = Future<groupMate, Never> { promise in
                self.ref.collection("Users").document(groupUserUID).getDocument(){
                    
                    (friendDocument, err) in
                
                    if let err = err {
                            print("Error getting documents \(err)")
                    } else {
                      //  print("friendDocument: \(String(describing: friendDocument?.data()))" )

                        let groupUsername = (friendDocument?.data()?["username"]) as! String
                        let groupUID = (friendDocument?.data()?["uid"]) as! String
                        let groupName = (friendDocument?.data()?["name"]) as! String
                        let groupPic = (friendDocument?.data()?["imageurl"]) as! String

                        promise(.success(groupMate(id: groupmateID, uid: groupUID , name: groupName , username: groupUsername, pic: groupPic)))
                    }
                    
                    groupmateID += 1
                }
            }
            print("in receiveCompletion")

            future.sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                print("in receiveCompletion")
                print(1, completion)
                switch completion {
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(3, error)
                        handler([])
                        return
                    case .finished:
                        break
                }
            },
            receiveValue: {
                print("in receiveValue")
                groupMates.append($0)
                print(groupMates)
                handler(groupMates)
            }).store(in: &cancellable)
        }
    }
    
    
    func creategroup(groupName: String){
        addedTogroupUsers.append(self.uid)
        
        print("here111")
        loadUserFromFirebase(groupUserIds: addedTogroupUsers) { groupMates in
            print("here222")

            let groupData: [String: Any] = [
                "groupName": "\(groupName)",
                "groupmates": groupMates
            ]
            print("here333 \(groupData)")

            print("groupMates are \(self.groupMates)")
            
            
            var groupref: DocumentReference? = nil
                groupref = self.ref.collection("groups").addDocument(data: groupData) { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error adding document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("Document added with ID: \(groupref!.documentID)")
                    for addedgroupUser in self.addedTogroupUsers {
                        self.ref.collection("Users").document(addedgroupUser).updateData([
                                "groups": FieldValue.arrayUnion([groupref!.documentID])
                            ])
                    }
                }
            }
                print("groupName is \(groupName) and addedTogroup are \(self.addedTogroupUsers)")
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to see if AnyCancellable is the way to go but since I'm using a chained array of future promises, I'm not sure how to implement it. Please let me know how you'd solve this problem so that the array does get populated since the documents do exist and the print inside the method call work but the groupMates array in the createGroup function prints an empty array afterwards. Thanks!

Edit: Added AnyCancallable to Code along with completion handler as suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dealing with async functions can be tricky. You are getting an empty array, because you are returning too early, in loadUserFromFirebase. Try this approach (untested) using the old style closure:

```
func loadUserFromFirebase(groupUserIds: [String], handler: @escaping ([groupMate]) -> Void) { // <-- here
        var groupmateID = 0
        var groupMates : [String] = []
        print("groupUserIds: \(groupUserIds)" )
        
        for groupUserUID in groupUserIds {
            print("groupUserUID: \(groupUserUID)" )
            
            let future = Future<groupMate, Never> { promise in
                self.ref.collection("Users").document(groupUserUID).getDocument(){ (friendDocument, err) in
                    if let err = err {
                            print("Error getting documents \(err)")
                    } else {
                        print("friendDocument: \(String(describing: friendDocument?.data()))" )
                        
                        let groupUsername = (friendDocument?.data()?["username"]) as! String
                        let groupUID = (friendDocument?.data()?["uid"]) as! String
                        let groupName = (friendDocument?.data()?["name"]) as! String
                        let groupPic = (friendDocument?.data()?["imageurl"]) as! String
                        
                        promise(.success(groupMate(id: groupmateID, uid: groupUID , name: groupName , username: groupUsername, pic: groupPic)))
                    }
                    groupmateID += 1
                }
            }
            
            future.sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                print("in receiveCompletion")
                print(1, completion)
                switch completion {
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(3, error)
                    handler([])  // <-- here
                    return          // <-- here
                case .finished:
                    break
                }
            },
            receiveValue: {
                print("in receiveValue")
                groupMates.append($0)
                print(groupMates)
                handler(groupMates)  // <-- here
            })
        }
        // <-- do not return here
    }

   
    func creategroup(groupName: String) {
        addedTogroupUsers.append(self.uid)
        
        // -- here wait until you get the data
        loadUserFromFirebase(groupUserIds: addedTogroupUsers) { groupMates in
            
            let groupData: [String: Any] = [
                "groupName": "\(groupName)",
                "groupmates": groupMates      // <-- here
            ]
            
            print("groupMates are \(self.groupMates)")
            
            var groupref: DocumentReference? = nil
            groupref = ref.collection("groups").addDocument(data: groupData) { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error adding document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("Document added with ID: \(groupref!.documentID)")
                    for addedgroupUser in self.addedTogroupUsers {
                        self.ref.collection("Users").document(addedgroupUser).updateData([
                            "groups": FieldValue.arrayUnion([groupref!.documentID])
                        ])
                    }
                }
            }
            print("groupName is \(groupName) and addedTogroup are \(addedTogroupUsers)")
        }
        
    }
```

Note, if you are targeting ios 15, macos 12, you are far better served if you use the swift 5.5 async/await/task features. They really work well.

EDIT: trying to return all results

```
func loadUserFromFirebase(groupUserIds: [String], handler: @escaping ([groupMate]) -> Void) {
    var groupmateID = 0
    var groupMates : [String] = []
    print("groupUserIds: \(groupUserIds)" )
    
    var arr: [Future<groupMate, Never>] = [Future<groupMate, Never>]()
    
    var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    for groupUserUID in groupUserIds {
        print("groupUserUID: \(groupUserUID)" )
        
        let future = Future<groupMate, Never> { promise in
            self.ref.collection("Users").document(groupUserUID).getDocument(){ (friendDocument, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("friendDocument: \(String(describing: friendDocument?.data()))" )
                    
                    let groupUsername = (friendDocument?.data()?["username"]) as! String
                    let groupUID = (friendDocument?.data()?["uid"]) as! String
                    let groupName = (friendDocument?.data()?["name"]) as! String
                    let groupPic = (friendDocument?.data()?["imageurl"]) as! String
                    
                    promise(.success(groupMate(id: groupmateID, uid: groupUID , name: groupName , username: groupUsername, pic: groupPic)))
                }
                groupmateID += 1
            }
        }
        arr.append(future)
    }
    
    Publishers.MergeMany(arr)
        .collect()
        .sink { _ in
            print("-----> merging ")
        } receiveValue: { value in
            print("-----> value: \(value)")
            groupMates = value  // <--- maybe append?
            print(groupMates)
            handler(groupMates)
        }
        .store(in: &cancellable)
}
```

Comment: Hi @workingdog thanks so much for the response! I unfortunately am targeting iOS 13+ so I can't use the swift 5.5 features. I tried updating it to use the handler but it seems to be stuck in the loadUserFromFirebase call and I tried to print right after the create group loadUserFromFirebase call which Never gets hit. Trying to see where the issue could be

Comment: It never seems to go to either the receiveCompletion or receiveValue. I'm wondering whether I'm calling the future.sink incorrectly or something. Its also looping through the groupUserIds so it does have multiple promises. I'm definitely very stuck and would appreciate any help. Thanks again!

Comment: I've forgotten how this all works with Futures and Promises, but don't you have to have 
something like this: 

var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()  // outside the function

future.sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
...
}).store(in: &cancellable)

Comment: Thank you so much! This has almost done the trick, I just have one final issue. It seems to be that the promise only accepts one of the users from the several in the loop. In my group mates array, I'd like it to store all the users. What should I change in the promise .success condition to ensure that all the users get added to the array rather than just the first success.

Comment: there is a "Publishers.MergeMany(f)" and ".collect()".
 Don't know how to use them,
 but I suspect the for loop you have is not a good fit for that.
 You may have to re-think the structure of your futures without the loop.

Comment: updated my answer with a possible approach. Let us know if it works with a few tweaks.